# AngularJS directive with isolate scope: passing params in a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I want to use &attr in the scope option in order to expose an API for outside controllers.

This is the way i'm currently use: [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/4LyIVdLq5isocdHzmWpA)

The problem is that i can only pass params inside an object, which forces the function binding to have one specific key (in the linking example, `test` inside `hideDialog(test)` is asked because i need it as key in the call `close({'test':'Letho'})`).

Is there any way that can omit the key when binding? So that i can directly use:

```
<my-dialog ng-hide="dialogIsHidden" on-close="hideDialog">
  Check out the contents, {{name}}!
</my-dialog>
```

and

```
<a href class="close" ng-click="close('Letho')">&times;</a>
```

Thanks.

Comment: I don't think you can do that, but you can pass an object back to the method instead of sending just a string, if you want to call with multiple arguments `{'test':{param1:'',param2:''}}`

Comment: @Chandermani Thanks for the comment. I just thinks that asking the binding to add an undeclared key 'test' looking like a bad code smell.

Comment: Can you expand further on how you want it to work? What do you want to be able to pass to hideDialog() in the markup, and what do you want to receive in the controller? Just trying to make sure I understand the use case.

Comment: @tasseKATT I've update my question. Is it clear now? I just want a clean way to bind function.

Comment: So you don't want the user of the my-dialog directive to specify what to pass to hideDialog, but want it specified from the template?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Directive usage:

```
<my-dialog ng-hide="dialogIsHidden" on-close="hideDialog">
```

Directive:

```
scope: {
  'onClose': '&'
},
templateUrl: 'my-dialog-close.html',
link: function (scope) {

  scope.close = function (value) {
    var expressionHandler = scope.onClose();
    expressionHandler(value);
  };
}
```

Directive template:

```
<a href class="close" ng-click="close('Letho')">&times;</a>
```

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/2pxIHoTAP1OeAhmhA9ow?p=preview

Comment: It works! Thanks! May i ask what's the meaning of the method `onClose`? How it works?